# Why was my edit with the intention to complete an answer rejected?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits, suggested-edits

I made the following suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2776889

With the edit, the answer is complete and useful to any person who reads the answer.
Without the edit, the next person who reads it will have to spend some hours to research what I already solved.

This is what the reviewers said:

- *This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post*: do you really think that all the code I added should be in a comment?
- *This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost*: it completes the original post, but does not change it.

I feel bad because I spent some time completing the answer just to help the next person who reads it, and the reviewers rejected it, possibly without reading what I wrote.

Comment: If you have to make an edit that substantial, it's best to make it an answer.

Comment: I recommend dropping the extensive editorial in your answer edits in general ("UPDATE", and the last line of your edit)

Comment: I could be a solution @ಠ_ಠ, but I'm angry now. Maybe I'll do it later.

Answer (score 20):

You should have posted a *new* answer in which you included all of that information.  That is the *proper* course of action for you to take when you have gone and done a considerable amount of research finding information not currently found in any of the other answers.  (Which is great by the way; don't get too discouraged by this, you're just learning the system.)

Editing that information into someone else's answer is not appropriate, and it was correct of those users to reject it.

If you feel that the existing answer has some good information you are welcome to reference it in your answer, and even quote or summarize some of what that answer includes.  Simply ensure that you properly cite the answer to indicate what content is not your own.

Comment: *"Which is great by the way"* ... couldn't agree more. Well done for that. A suggested edit is just not really the appropriate way to post it.

Comment: I didn't edit any information of our mate. I complete his answer. I don't think it is correct to copy and paste his answer to add my code at the end. If I write my answer referencing the answer of our mate and check my answer as the correct I think is unfair for him as the half of the answer is his. Futhermore, is less clear to have the answer cut in two different posts. I won't waste my time more with this issue. But it is just a pity for the next person who has the same problem so he/she will find the answer incomplete.

Comment: @chelder What you could do is point to the suggested edit and ask the author of the answer to incorporate it himself. If he does, problem solved.

Comment: @chelder And yet you're sticking words in someone else's mouth as it is.  What if some of your content isn't correct?  What if the author of that post doesn't agree with some of that content, or doesn't think that it's a proper solution to this problem?  In the end it's his answer, and he is responsible for the content within it.  If you posted a new answer you wouldn't need to copy his entire answer, merely summarize some of the important points. Having valuable information in two different answers is *fine*. There's nothing wrong with that.  You can leave that answer as accepted if you wish.

Comment: @chelder: Create a new answer, and start it with something like "Credit to Mr X for the ground work, but it wasn't enough on it's own to solve my issue. So here is the full solution which worked for me..."

Comment: @chelder: In fact, [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7795347/838807) of a time I did something very similar, and now I have more upvotes than the accepted answer from doing so. And someone on there actually "stole" my answer and made an edit

Comment: And which answer is the correct one? mine? That's unfair for our mate. I'm thankful for his help and I want to keep his answer as the correct one.

Comment: @chelder Which you're certainly welcome to do, if you want, as I already said.  You don't have to accept your own answer instead, unless you want to.  It is *entirely* up to you which answer you accept.

Comment: Again, his answer worked for me. I just added code to complete it.

Comment: @chelder Great.  So add that code as a new answer if you want to share it with others.

Comment: I copy and paste the markdown code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2776889 to the end of my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370593/spring-security-core-and-custom-validator-for-a-confirm-password-field-is-possib) (UPDATE 2). But the result is ugly. How could I copy and paste it? On the other hand, I didn't receive any alert telling me the edit wasn't accepted. I think he should be notified.

Comment: @chelder You should *not* be editing an answer into the question itself.  Post it as an answer if its an answer.  As for why the markup was garbled, for some reason you removed all of the line breaks.  Not sure why that happened; it doesn't happen when I copy from that page.

Comment: I don't know either. I guess a privilegies stuff.